# What is the best practice for bundling third party libraries with your python project? (for users with no Internet)

Tags: python, dependencies, project, static-libraries, directory-structure

I'm trying to build a project which includes a few open source third party libraries, but I want to bundle my distribution with said libraries - because I expect my users to want to use my project without an Internet connection. Additionally, I'd like to leave their code 100% untouched and even leave their directory structure untouched if I can. My approach so far has been to extract the tarballs and place the entire folder in `MyProject/lib`, but I've had to put `__init__.py` in every sub-directory to be able to reference the third-party code in my own modules.

What's the common best practice for accomplishing this task? How can I best respect the apps' developers by retaining their projects' structure? How can I make importing these libraries in my code less painful?

I'm new to making a distributable project in Python, so I've no clue if there's something I can do in `__init__.py` or in `setup.py` to keep myself from having to type `from lib.app_name.app_name.app_module include *` and whatnot.

For what it's worth, I will be distributing this on OS X and possibly *nix. I'd like to avoid using another library (e.g. `setuptools`) to accomplish this. (Weirdly, it seems to already be installed on my system, but I didn't install it, so I've no idea what's going on.)

I realize that this question seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5862599/691859), but I don't think it is because I'm asking for the best practice for the "distribute-the-third-party-code-with-your-own" approach. Please forgive me if I'm asking a garbage question.

Comment: I'd like to add that while fiddling around with alternatives I've seen on similar questions on SO, I found that I could `import setuptools` [on a clean install of OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14316836/691859)... does Apple bundle setuptools with Python? (I doubt I can rely on this in future versions of OS X, but I'm just curious.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) is good solution for building and distributing Python software.

Comment: Is that licensed under the ZPL? I can't tell, they don't have a LICENSE file in their repo, but when I searched their docs I found a link to the ZPL embedded in their [setup file](http://www.buildout.org/docs/tutorial.html?highlight=license#polished-setup-py-2-3).

Comment: @agarrett There is a [LICENSE.txt](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) file in the repo, and their `setup.py` also lists the license. It's the ZPL (2.1). The link *you* found is for `zope.event` and appears to be an example for the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks @delnan, I guess I didn't think to look in a subdirectory. I'll keep this one in mind but I'd like to avoid the ZPL.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the inner workings of virtualenv to get some inspiration how go about this. Maybe you can resuse code from there.

Comment: Seems nice, but wouldn't I have to bundle virtualenv with my project? Seems like a chicken-and-egg solution, although maybe I don't understand. Either way, I'd like to avoid using another third-party library if I can, but I'll keep this one in mind because it seems tidy.

Comment: A virtualenv is tied to the exact path it was created at (there is a "relocation" feature but it's experimental and AFAIR doesn't work on Windows at all).

Comment: Certainly, there will be issues that need to be resolved. BTW, the OP asked for OS X and maybe *nix, not Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed. Still, it indicates how unpolished and hacky the support is. Also, the virtualenv is platform-specific in any case, and even depends on details of the Python build, so you'd need separate virtualenvs for different operating systems and different linux distros. More generally, virtualenv isn't designed or intended for this, so I expect there to be further issues.

Comment: You have to do more for sure. I updated my answer accordingly. These type of problems need longer time to think about.

Comment: Making a build for each new version of OS X, potentially, is very much an impedance. But I thank you for the suggestion nonetheless :)